# Prove that if $r(x)≠r(y)$ for every 2 distinct vertices $x$ and $y$ of $D$ then $D$ contain a Hamiltonian path.

Tags: graph-theory

> A vertex $v$ in digraph $D$ is said to be **reachable**. from a vertex $u$ in $D$ if $D$ contains a $u-v$ path.

Let $D$ be a digraph and for each vertex $u$ of $D$, let $R(u)$ be the set of vertices reachable from $u$ and let $r(u)=|R(u)|$. Since $u∈R(u)$ for every vertex  $u∈D$, it follows  that $r(u)≥1$. Prove that if $r(x)≠r(y)$ for every 2 distinct vertices $x$ and $y$ of $D$ then $D$ contain a Hamiltonian path.

Let $D$ be a digraph of order $n$ and label vertices of $D$ $\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_m \}$ such that $r(v_i)=i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. So there are $i$ vertices that is reachable from $v_i$. So the vertex $v_n$ is reachable to it self and $n-1$ other vertices. So there is a path from $v_n$ to $v_{n-1}$.

Claim: $v_{n-1}$ also reachable to it self and $n-2$ other vertice. Proof: assume that there is a vertex $w$ such that there is no path from $v_{n-1}$ to $w$.

Case 1: if $w=v_n$ then we have a path between $v_{n-1}$ and $w$

Case 2: if $w \not =v_n$ then there is a path from $v_n$ to $w$, thus there must be a path between $v_{n-1}$ and $w$

both cases lead to  $v_{n-1}$ also reachable to it self and $n-2$ other vertice

Claim: the path between $v_n$ and $v_{n-1}$ must be an arc. Proof: Assume that there is some vertex $v_k$ lie on the $v_n -v_{n-1}$ path, then $v_k$ is reachable to $v_n, v_{n-1}$ and all other vertices, which cause $v_k$ to have bigger index then $v_n$ , but $v--N$ have the highest index, thus this is a contradiction and the path between $v_n$ and $v_{n-1}$ must be an arc.

Repeating the argument that the path between $v_{n-1}$ and $v_{n-2}$ must be an arc and so on, we have a directed halmiltonian path $v_n \to v_{n-1} \to \dots \to v_1$

Does my argument sound acceptable?

Comment: With the given data the Hamiltonian path has to be $v_n\to v_{n-1}\to\cdots\to v_2\to v_1$. So what you need to do is prove that those edges actually exist.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, that what the book told me to do. Because $v_i$ is reachable, so it look like a sink, everything come into it without coming out, so how can there be such path pass through $v_i$?

Comment: x @Diane, you know $v_i$ has to reach $i$ vertices. None of those can have _higher_ index then $i$, because then $v_i$ would be able to reach too many vertices. So the $i$ places that are reachable from $v_i$ must be exactly $\{v_1,\ldots,v_i\}$ ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm From your hint, I came up with a proof, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly, would you check it for me please.

Comment: That sounds correct.  If you want to make it more succinct, you can use induction to show that the path is $v_nv_{n-1} \ldots v_1$.  Find an easy base case with say $n = 2$ vertices, then work on a digraph with $n + 1$ vertices.  When you remove $v_{n + 1}$ from this digraph, you know there is a path that starts at $v_n$, so all you have to do is find the arc between $v_{n+1}$ and $v_n$.